# Application crashes on clicking a link in TextView

Tags: java, android, hyperlink, crash, textview

I am working on an application called Android Glossary. In my second activity I have created a TextView which has a link embedded in it. Everything seems fine; the link is highlighted in blue. The problem is that when I click on the link, my application crashes down. I don't know what is wrong. Please help.

Code in my second activity :

```
package com.mavenmaverick.androidglossary;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_c);

    TextView link = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);
    link.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Uri adress= Uri.parse("http;//www.cyanogenmod.com");  
            Intent browser= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, adress);  
            startActivity(browser);             
        }
    });

}
```

[image: Emulator screenshot]

Comment: upload logcat n code snippet please

Comment: Need microscope to read your code and error. Add code into text

Comment: and also manifest file code

Comment: Are you adding Internet permissions in manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see your code

you have enter url like

```
 Uri adress= Uri.parse("http;//www.cyanogenmod.com");
```

replace with this

```
   Uri adress= Uri.parse("http://www.cyanogenmod.com");
```

problm is **;** in **Http;** replace with **http:**

Answer (score 0):

you should use setData()

```
String url = "http://www.cynogenmod.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView link = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);
link.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent browser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.cyanogenmod.com"));
    startActivity(browser);            
    }
});
```